# How to lock orientation in some views in Titanium app

Tags: android, view, titanium, ios7, orientation-changes

I'm doing an application for Android and IOS. In this application, I have a window, and I add/remove different views with the content.

I want that the first view will be only in portrait mode, whereas the rest of the views can be in any orientation.

How can I do it?

With titanium SDK 3.1.2 it works more or less on IOS:

My window:

```
var appWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({    
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    height : utils.getScreenHeight(),
    width : utils.getScreenWidth(),    
    backgroundColor : "#393a3a",
    //fullscreen : true,    
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT],    
});
```

Then, when I want to load a view:

```
var openWindow = function(e) {    
    appWindow.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];

    if (e.win == 'Home') {
        Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT;
        appWindow.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT];
        orientacion = 0;
        activeView = Home.Constructor(appWindow);
    } else if (e.win == 'configuracion') {
        Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT;
        orientacion = 0;
        appWindow.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT];
        activeView = Configuracion.Constructor(appWindow);
    } else if (e.win == 'Circle') {
        activeView = Circle.Constructor(appWindow);
    }
    appWindow.add(activeView);
};
```

Now, I want to use SDK 3.1.3 to support IOS 7, and it doesn't work, none of the views allow to rotate.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not have any luck with changing a windows orientationModes on runtime too. The docs say that the window property `orientationModes` as well as its method `setOrientationModes` have to be set **before** opening the window.

So switching from views to windows is not an option?

If you want a window to allow orientations different from those defined in tiapp.xml, you have to set orientationModes on every window individually:

```
// This window allows orientations defined in tiapp.xml
var appWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor = '#FFF'
});
appWin.open();

// This window is portrait only
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
});
win.open();

// If this window is opened it allows multiple orientations
var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
});
newWindow.open()
```

This is tested with SDK 3.1.3.

**Edit**
To make this work on Android, you have to force a heavyweight window by either setting `fullscreen: true` or `navBarHidden: true`

Comment: I've tried it on ios and it works great. But on Android it doesn't work. Do I have to put anything  more? Thank you very much

Comment: For Android windows you could try setting `fullscreen: true` to force a heavyweight window.

Comment: I want to not show title bar in Android, so, I need fullscreen : false. Finally, I've solved it with this: fullscreen : false,
 navBarHidden : true, when I create the window, and then:
winPortrait.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT];

Comment: Glad you could solve it, basically `navBarHidden : true` has the same effect as fullscreen. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `AndroidManifest.xml` and set `screenOrientation` attribute for the `activities` you want.-

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

More information [here](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/09/locking-android-orientation-mode.html)

Comment: Ok, but, I want to lock portrait orientation only in some views and in the other views allow any orientation. I think that android manifest affects all app, doesn't it? and I want it for Android and IOS. Thanks

Comment: Didn't try it, but I'm guessing if you don't set `screenOrientation` for an Activity, it will keep changing orientation behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With titanium SDK 3.1.2 I put the following code for:

```
Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT;
appWindow.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT];
```

and then, when you load other view, then put:

```
appWindow.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];
```

Comment: This is what I have now. It doesn't work with SDK 3.1.3 and I would like to use SDK 3.1.3 because I have some problems with ios 7. Thanks